# Hot code replace failed - VM may be inconsistence

Tags: spring-mvc, jvm, java-8, spring-tool-suite, glassfish-4.1

[image]

Hot Code Replace Failed, this message appeared while working in STS. Does JVM doesn't support hot code replace.

Answer (score 1):

> Does JVM doesn't support hot code replace.

This means the JVM attempted to hot replace your class, however it cannot handle all possible replacements.  e.g. you cannot;

- add a field and have it modify existing objects.
- modify a method signature and expect call using the old signature to call it.
- there is a number of limitations depending on your JVM.

I suggest you limit yourself to modifying the contents of methods and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you have attached the eclipse debugger to a process you can check the jvm capabilities in the properties of the launched process.

[image: vm capabilities]